# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCustomModal' of undefined

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I am new to Javascript and I am following some tutorial on to displaying pdfs with PDFTron. However I am having issues with setting custom properties. Could you please advise where am I making the mistake?

```
 window.webviewerFunctions = {
      initWebViewer: function () {
          const viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
          WebViewer({
              path: 'lib',
              initialDoc: 'lib/simpledoc.pdf', // replace with your own PDF file
          }, viewerElement)
          .then((instance) => {
              instance.setTheme('dark');
              instance.disableElements(['downloadButton','printButton' ]);
              instance.disableElements(['toolbarGroup-Insert']);
             
              
          })
          .then(function(instance) {
            var modal = {
              dataElement: 'meanwhileInFinlandModal',
              render: function renderCustomModal(){
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.style.color = 'white';
                div.style.backgroundColor = 'hotpink';
                div.style.padding = '20px 40px';
                div.style.borderRadius = '5px';
                div.innerText = 'Meanwhile in Finland';
                return div
              }
            }
            instance.setCustomModal(modal);
            instance.openElements([modal.dataElement]);
            });
      }
    };
```

Comment: You need to return `instance` in the first `then`. Or maybe you could combine the `then`s?

Comment: could you please show me an example

Comment: `return instance`?

Comment: either, as I said I am veery new to this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values#using_return_values_in_your_own_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Promise handler needs to return `instance` because that is what is passed as an input to the next handler in the chain.

```
   .then((instance) => {
              instance.setTheme('dark');
              instance.disableElements(['downloadButton','printButton' ]);
              instance.disableElements(['toolbarGroup-Insert']);
              return instance;
          })
```